# Can't stop the windows services, after install services with instsrv.exe and srvany.exe

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, installation

> I had installed windows services by instsrv.exe and srvany.exe.
>
> The service was install successfully and work normal.
>
> But i can't stop the services in "Windows service page",which page is win+r -> services.msc.
>
> The only way i can stop it is command "taskkill /f /pid processnum".
>
> How do I manually stop the Windows service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Srvany is a "service wrapper". It is designed to accept commands from the Services Control Manager (SCM) and perform appropriate actions on your non-service application.

The SCM can send several commands to a Windows Service, including "Start", "Stop", "Pause" and "Resume". The problem with srvany is that it only takes sensible action on the "Start" command!

When you start a srvany service, it runs the command line you specified. But when you stop the service, the srvany process simply exits. The service will transition to the stopped state but your application will remain running in the background. **Srvany will not end your application**, and there is no way to get it to do so.

Comment: if i want stop the application ,which started by srvany.The only way is use cmd command taskkill /f /pid [pidNum],any else way?

Comment: You can terminate the executable from Task Manager (or Microsoft's Process Explorer) but taskkill is the way to go when working from the command line.